# How to log request specific property in python logger

Tags: python, logging, server

I have a python file 'server.py'

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, BaseHTTPServer
from mylogger import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class RESTRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        logger.error('Just random log')
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

def rest_server(port):
    'Starts the REST server'
    http_server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', port), RESTRequestHandler)
    print 'Starting HTTP server at port %d' % port
    try:
        http_server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    print 'Stopping HTTP server'
    http_server.server_close()

def main(argv):
    rest_server(8080)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I have another file 'mylogger.py'

```
__all__ = ['logging']

import logging
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s | %(tid)d | %(message)s'

def req_extractor(*args, **kargs):
    print(args)
    print(kargs)
    print(locals())
    # here i want to get request X-App-Tid
    return {'tid': 1}

class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None):
        reqObj = req_extractor()
        if extra is None: extra = {}
        reqObj.update(extra)
        super(CustomLogger, self)._log(level, msg, args, exc_info, reqObj)

logging.setLoggerClass(CustomLogger)

logging.basicConfig(
        filename='python.log',
        format=FORMAT,
        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
        level=logging.DEBUG)
```

when i make a curl call

```
curl -H 'X-App-Tid:1' -i http://localhost:8080
```

i get

```
07/23/2019 04:50:45 PM | 1 | Just random log
```

I am able to print `tid` in log, but i want to extract it from the request header `X-App-Tid`

Note : The file server.py is not allowed to change, but i can make any change in mylogger.py

Any help?

Comment: This is possible by going through the [stacktrace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html), but it is very far from fun or recommended. It would be much easier if you can pass in something to the logger call in server.py. `logger.error('Just random log', self.headers)`

Comment: @blues there are 100s of file like `server.py`, i can't change each and line in each and every file.

Comment: can it be done with flask server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can update your logger like below to override the existing class

```py
__all__ = ['logging']

import logging

import BaseHTTPServer
org = BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler

current_class = None

class MyClass(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler, object):

   def parse_request(self):
       global current_class
       current_class = self
       value =  super(MyClass, self).parse_request()

       return value

BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler = MyClass       

FORMAT = '%(asctime)s | %(tid)d | %(message)s'

def req_extractor(*args, **kargs):
    print(args)
    print(kargs)
    print(locals())
    global current_class
    if current_class:
       print current_class.headers['X-App-Tid']
    # here i want to get request 
    return {'tid': 1}

class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None):
        reqObj = req_extractor()
        if extra is None: extra = {}
        reqObj.update(extra)
        super(CustomLogger, self)._log(level, msg, args, exc_info, reqObj)

logging.setLoggerClass(CustomLogger)

logging.basicConfig(
        filename='python.log',
        format=FORMAT,
        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
        level=logging.DEBUG)
```

And then it will work

[image: Header printed]

Answer (score 1):

One (ugly) solution using traceback as mentioned in the comments:

```
def req_extractor():
    import inspect
    try:
        return {'tid': int(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_back.f_locals['self'].headers['X-App-Tid'])}
    except:
        return {'tid': 0}
```